# Devise: Don't redirect on password reset if already logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

If a user is already logged in and clicks on a password reset link from their email, they automatically get redirected to the logged in area.  I want the user to be able to reset their password, logged in or not.  How do I prevent the redirect?

Comment: For anyone looking for a solution without using the Registerable module, I found the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967405/devise-forgot-password-for-logged-in-user pretty useful

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is, use Devise `recoverable` module to change a logged in user password. This is not what `recoverable` module was built for.

As per `carlosantoniodasilva`, a Collaborator of Devise

> This feature is for recovering passwords, not for signed in users
>   change their passwords. If you want that, you can use Registerable
>   module or handle it by yourself.

`Registerable` module handles signing up users through a registration process, also allowing them to edit and destroy their account.