# Laravel native password reset after logged in

Tags: laravel

I don't want to invent a wheel again... In laravel there is a password reset for someone who forget it. I want to use it if someone is logged in and for some reasons want to reset password (with additional security which is e-mail verification with token link).

When I'm logged in and when I try to go to {{ url('/password/reset') }} I'm redirected to standard homepage for my app. Where can I hook up to add logout before show {{ url('/password/reset') }} to user?

I found some information here ([Devise: Don't redirect on password reset if already logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207785/devise-dont-redirect-on-password-reset-if-already-logged-in)) about that subject but I don't understend why I shouldn't use it that way.

Comment: Do you have the proper route and method in controller for reset. Share if yes.

Comment: @MunnuBala this is native route, method and controller that I get after php artisan make:auth.

Answer (score 0):

For now I've done it simple by call to attached function when someone click button to reset password on settings page. But I think I can do it better by hooking up in some place when logged in user try to get {{ url('/password/reset') }} page.

```
public function outForReset() {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('password/reset');
    }
```